# How do you use pytest-html in a program to generate a html report and the IDE PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest-html

I'm launching my test from PyCharm, and once it finishes I want to create a report. How can I do that in my code?

I saw the pytest_html module but I have only see a command (`pytest --html=report.html --self-contained-html`) to put on *cmd.exe*, and I want to know how to do thaht directly in my program?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("pytest --html=report.html --self-contained-html",shell=True)
```